# Cannot run memory intense program on Spark through YARN

Tags: azure, apache-spark, benchmarking, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to benchmark a program on an Azure cluster using Spark. We previously ran this on EC2 and know that 150 GB of RAM is sufficient. I have tried multiple setups for the executors and given them 160-180GB of RAM but regardless of what I do, the program dies due to executors requesting more memory.

What can I do? Are there more launch options I should consider, I have tried every conceivable executor setup and nothing seems to want to work. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: This question is very broad. You can try first by giving a more detailed description than "the program dies". We don't even know what options you are considering now. Which version of spark are you using ? Running on which version of Hadoop ? How much memory for the executors ? Driver ?

Comment: @eliasah I just don't know very much, detail wise it really does just die, it has executor memory errors and eventually goes to, "too many executor failures." As for the other info, I am using 1.6.0, no idea the Hadoop version (whichever version HDInsight uses). I have tried multiple executor settings, none seem to work.

Comment: Can you share the submit command that executes your app ?

Comment: @eliasah sure here it is: `spark-submit --class <classname> --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 40g --driver-memory 4g <jarpath>`

Answer (score 0):

For your command, you specified 7 executor and each with 40g of memory. That's 280G of memory in total, but you said your cluster has only 160-180 G of memory? If only 150G of memory is needed, why the spark-submit is configured that way?

What's your HDI cluster node type and how many of them you created?

Were you using YARN previously on EC2 as well? In that case, are the configuration the same?

Comment: That executor setup is wrong, I have a correct one trying to run now. I have 4 nodes with 8 cores each, 56GB of ram per node. We did not use YARN in EC2, just normal submission, but I don't think Azure allows you to submit to the cluster without YARN.